# Curly bracket under a sum

Tags: brackets, braces

I would like to type something similar to the following:

[image: sum of k ones]

i.e., a sum of `k` ones. Is there an easy way to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: `\underbrace{1+1+\ldots+1}_{k}` in math-mode

Comment: I would prefer `\cdots` .

Comment: @EthanBolker Or, even better, `\dots` with `mathtools` (or `amsmath`) loaded.

Comment: @Manuel: That's a matter of taste ;-) The basic question was about the underbrace, not about the `\?dots` command ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's a matter of taste. But the *correct* command is `\dots` which is “intelligent”. Of course if you prefer a different output you cannot write `\dots` as is.